# Rails will_paginate how to generate full urls?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I use will_paginate in my app and the pagination links have hrefs like 'posts?page=2' but I want them to be 'http://www.fu.com/posts?page=2'. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to monkey-patch the default LinkRenderer, so the urls are generated with the correct options.

In the [`url` method of WillPaginate's Rails Helpers](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/b828d8c9fc9aab21695cb2b2ae3a4eaaaa918983/lib/will_paginate/view_helpers/action_view.rb#L111) you have

```
    @base_url_params ||= begin
      url_params = merge_get_params(default_url_params)
      url_params[:only_path] = true
      merge_optional_params(url_params)
    end
```

so the `:only_path` option is forced to be `true`. But you can make `merge_optional_params`, which is called afterwards, do the trick for you:

```
module WillPaginateForceFullUrl
  def merge_optional_params(url_params)
    url_params = super
    url_params[:only_path] = false
    url_params
  end
end

WillPaginate::ActionView::LinkRenderer.prepend(WillPaginateForceFullUrl)
```

Stick this code in an initializer, or under lib, but ensure it is loaded from an initializer. Your URLs should contain the full url now.